# Using modproxy to get around China's Great Firewall

Tags: apache, proxy

I'm using WIX service and I like it very much.  However, one big problem is that some of my colleagues are in China but their IP is blocked.

I'm wondering if modproxy can help me.  I would like to setup a clean server (not blocked by the stupid Chinese government).  Pointed the DNS cname to it and have modproxy get the page in background and send the page to viewers in China.  Will it work?  If yes, can anyone post any examples?  Thanks a million

Comment: You're better off setting up a VPN server on a clean IP (or pool of them) and have your colleagues use that to access the service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, modproxy is the solution.  Here's what I have done:

1. Set up Wix site to a dummy URL (both in wix and in your DNS), e.g. `www.dummy.com`
2. Set up an Amazon EC2 instance, in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName www.real.com
       ProxyPass / http://www.dummy.com/ 
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
3. point `www.real.com` to your EC2
4. restart service httpd